# How to extract data from a json array with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, twitter

I am trying to extract the full_name value from the below json. I have been able to extract from the "query" section using this code.

```
echo $data->query->params->granularity;
```

This prints out `neighbourhood`.

But I am unable to echo the `full_name`. Im guessing this is because I have to do something different because of the `[]` but I'm new to this and not at sure what to do.

None of these seem to work.

```
foreach ($data['places'] as $item) { ough!
echo $item->result->places->contained_within->attributes->full_name;
echo $item->result->places->full_name;
echo $item->result->full_name;
echo $item->full_name;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
  "query": {
    "params": {
      "accuracy": 0,
      "coordinates": {
        "coordinates": [
          -122.42284884,
          37.76893497
        ],
        "type": "Point"
      },
      "granularity": "neighborhood"
    },
    "type": "reverse_geocode"
  },
  "result": {
    "places": [
      {
        "attributes": {

        },
        "bounding_box": {
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [
                -122.42676492,
                37.75983003
              ],
              [
                -122.420736,
                37.75983003
              ],
              [
                -122.420736,
                37.77226299
              ],
              [
                -122.42676492,
                37.77226299
              ]
            ]
          ],
          "type": "Polygon"
        },
        "contained_within": [
          {
            "attributes": {

            },
            "bounding_box": {
              "coordinates": [
                [
                  [
                    -122.51368188,
                    37.70813196
                  ],
                  [
                    -122.35845384,
                    37.70813196
                  ],
                  [
                    -122.35845384,
                    37.83245301
                  ],
                  [
                    -122.51368188,
                    37.83245301
                  ]
                ]
              ],
              "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "US",
            "full_name": "San Francisco, CA",
            "id": "5a110d312052166f",
            "name": "San Francisco",
            "place_type": "city"
          }
        ],
        "country": "United States",
        "country_code": "US",
        "full_name": "Mission Dolores, San Francisco",
        "id": "cf7afb4ee6011bca",
        "name": "Mission Dolores",
        "place_type": "neighborhood"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid...

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for having a look. Thats not the full json its only a portion. The JSON came straight from twitter. you can see the all of it at this link.https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/geo/reverse_geocode

Comment: `$item->full_name` might work hard to say without seeing full JSON

Comment: PHP's `print_r()` is a little more verbose and will help you determine how to get each variable. http://pastebin.com/3hyWTNGu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem the json is not valid. There are few issue. You can validate at following website: http://jsonlint.com/

And the json have two full name. So following code will help to extract those two full names.

```
$json = 'Assign the json here';
$json_array = json_decode($json);
echo $json_array->result->places[0]->contained_within[0]->full_name;
echo $json_array->result->places[0]->full_name;
```

- Assign the valid json to the variable `$json` within single quot (') as json have double quot.

The tested code available here: http://sugunan.net/demo/json1.php

If we take your foreach example it need to be modified like follows. But that is not tested answer.

```
foreach ($data['places'] as $item) {
echo $item->contained_within[0]->full_name;
echo $item->full_name;
}
```

Following is the validated json of the above. Which had few unnecessary ",". And it missed few brackets.

```
{
"query": {
    "params": {
        "accuracy": 0,
        "coordinates": {
            "coordinates": [
                -122.42284884,
                37.76893497
            ],
            "type": "Point"
        },
        "granularity": "neighborhood"
    },
    "type": "reverse_geocode"
},
"result": {
    "places": [
        {
            "attributes": {},
            "bounding_box": {
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -122.42676492,
                            37.75983003
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.420736,
                            37.75983003
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.420736,
                            37.77226299
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.42676492,
                            37.77226299
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "type": "Polygon"
            },
            "contained_within": [
                {
                    "attributes": {},
                    "bounding_box": {
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [
                                    -122.51368188,
                                    37.70813196
                                ],
                                [
                                    -122.35845384,
                                    37.70813196
                                ],
                                [
                                    -122.35845384,
                                    37.83245301
                                ],
                                [
                                    -122.51368188,
                                    37.83245301
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "type": "Polygon"
                    },
                    "country": "United States",
                    "country_code": "US",
                    "full_name": "San Francisco, CA",
                    "id": "5a110d312052166f",
                    "name": "San Francisco",
                    "place_type": "city"
                }
            ],
            "country": "United States",
            "country_code": "US",
            "full_name": "Mission Dolores, San Francisco",
            "id": "cf7afb4ee6011bca",
            "name": "Mission Dolores",
            "place_type": "neighborhood"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me.I have this but it only returns a blank page when run. <?
include "library/twitteroauth.php";


//twitter app key details
$consumer ="";
$consumersecret = "";
$accesstoken = "";
$accesstokensecret = "";
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer,$consumersecret,$accesstoken,$accesstokensecret);


$json = $twitter-> get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/reverse_geocode.json?lat=37.76893497&long=-122.42284884');

$json_array = json_decode($json);
echo $json_array->result->places[0]->contained_within[0]->full_name;
echo $json_array->result->places[0]->full_name;
?>

Comment: is it working? Try to echo $json; and check wether the json is valid. At following web site http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Hey yeah I got it to work by adding json_encode to the api call. $json = json_encode($twitter->get('apiurl')); Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looping **from** "places" already, the `full_name` property would be in `$item->full_name` already.

Same goes for the `contained_within` struct, `$item->contained_within->full_name` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just so you know json_encode and decode seemed to be the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

A quick guide to accessing items within a decoded JSON data structure:

Run your json through a validator/formatter so you can see the structure. I use [this formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) as you can open and close the nodes to see the structure easily.

When you do `json_decode($json_string)`, PHP's json decoder creates objects and (non-associative) arrays. To access data in objects, use the syntax `$object->Attribute`. To access data in arrays, give the index of the array item: `$array[0]` for the first item, `$array[1]` for the second item, etc.

Examples:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo "accuracy: " . $data->query->params->accuracy . "\n";
// output: "accuracy: 0"
echo "coord 1: " . $data->query->params->coordinates->coordinates[0] . "\n";
// output: "coord 1: -122.42284884"

foreach ($data->query->params->coordinates->coordinates as $c)
    echo "coord: " . $c . "\n"
// output: 
// coord: -122.42284884
// coord: 37.76893497
```

To get items deeper in the data structure, chain together these accessors. For example, to get `full_name`, you would use the following:

```
echo "Full name: " . $data->result->places[0]->full_name . "\n";
// output: Full name: Mission Dolores, San Francisco
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help, had to add json_encode to the api call but got it working thankfully!

Answer (score 0):

After I had fixed your JSON (probably copy-paste errors) I have accessed the first (lowest branch) `full_name` by using:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->result->places as $item) {
  echo $item->name; // Mission Dolores, San Francisco
}
```

And the second element named `full_name` by using:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->result->places as $item) {
  foreach($item->contained_within as $cont) {
    echo $cont->full_name; // San Francisco, CA
  }
}
```

The philosophy behind parsing JSON is that some elements have one set of named element for a level, and the other has a number of recurring sets of elements. In this case there is a element called `result -> places` which can be more than one. And in there there is an element called `contained_within` which has more elements of its own. The correct way is looping over them using `for`/`foreach` but they can also be directly adressed:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->result->places[0]->full_name; // Mission Dolores, San Francisco
echo $data->result->places[0]->contained_within[0]->full_name; // San Francisco, CA
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out. I got it working

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode your json first then do a foreach...you can try this

```
$json = json_decode("YOUR JSON HERE");
foreach ($json->result->places as $place) {
    echo $place->full_name;
}
```

Comment: Hey Rafael, you were on the money, I also had to first encode the api call